# Fetching the missed orders during development after migration

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I have upgraded magento1.x website to magento2. Actually, I upgraded DB using data migration tool. After the data migration, worked with theme setup in development server. Now the website is ready. And during the development of theme, I placed some orders too.

But now, the problem is, after theme and modules setup which is nearly after two months, website has to be made live. So the problem is, for these two months, there were some orders in the old site. We need to fetch those too.

As the upgraded DB has lot of content changes, It's not able to go back with the migration tool. How can we fetch the missed orders during the development period?

Answer (score 0):

You successfully have done data migration with Magento2. After that, your changes in new setup/database.

Now if you want to get a new order, the customer from an old database then you want to require **delta migration process** with old database.

Please execute this command,

> php bin/magento migrate:delta vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.8.0.0/config.xml

Replace 1.8.0.0 with your old Magento1 version and execute this config.xml file with delta process.

If delta migration is working properly and you want to abort this process then when terminal display **ctrl + c** then click Ctrl + c. means you stop this delta migration process.

I hope this will help you.